# How do I render my home page after login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React and am developing a web page as a project.

I want when a user open my web page, he/she will have only the Login and Registration component be there, and *no* header or navigation bar will be there.

After the user successfully log ins then he/she will have a header, navbar and other components, and all the Link, Route and Routes will be there.

I am unable to understand what to render in App.js. That is my App.js code, and in the Login component there is a Login & registration form. From Login, I render a dashboard (the home page).

How can I do that any idea?

```js
import './App.css';
import {Login} from "./loginPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Login/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can conditionally render elements based on state.  When a user "logs in", what state value is changed?  That is, throughout the application how will you know that a user has successfully logged in?

Comment: for that am using Hooks,
I just want to know that how to render the header with browser router

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render elements.  For example, let's say you have some state value:

```
const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(true);
```

Then you can use that value to conditionally render one thing or the other:

```
return (
  <>
    {showLogin ? <Login/> : <Dashboard/>}
  </>
);
```

So in this case when `showLogin` is `true` then the `<Login/>` component renders, otherwise the `<Dashboard/>` component renders.

The question then becomes...

> What state value will you use and how will you define your condition?

That part is really up to you.  Whatever state is being modified by `<Login/>` to indicate that the user has successfully logged in, that's the state you would examine in your condition to determine if the user should see the login prompt or the dashboard interface (or whatever you're showing).

That `<Dashboard/>` can of course be anything.  For example, if you're using a routing system, you might render that instead:

```
return (
  <>
    {showLogin ? <Login/> : 
      <Router>
        <!-- your routes here, etc. -->
      </Router>
    }
  </>
);
```

Any JSX hierarchy will work, just like it would work anywhere else in the JSX.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create a state called "loggedIn" or anything or your choice. And add a condition (you can use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)). If it's true, then render the component.

```
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

{loggedIn ? <Navbar />: ""}
{loggedIn ? <Header /> : ""}
```

This way, even when the session expires and the user is logged out you just have to change one state and these components will be hidden again.